# how to mock firestore in firebase

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, go, google-cloud-firestore

I have a gRPC server which uses firestore as DB, and I am looking for examples how to mock firestore.

So far I did:

gRPC server

```golang
const (
    bufSize   = 1024 * 1024
)

var lis *bufconn.Listener

func init() {
    lis = bufconn.Listen(bufSize)
    s := grpc.NewServer()

    app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
    }

    client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing firestore: %v\n", err)
    }

    pb.RegisterBlogServiceServer(s, &server{app: app, firestore: client})
    go func() {
        if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Server exited with error: %v\n", err)
        }
    }()
}

func bufDialer(context.Context, string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return lis.Dial()
}
```

Now I would like to test verify Add function which is adding document to firestore

```golang
func Test_server_AddUsers(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    creds := grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials())
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, "bufnet", grpc.WithContextDialer(bufDialer), creds)

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to dial bufnet: %v", err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()
    c := user.NewUserClient(conn)
    client, server, err := mockfs.New()
    assert.NotNil(t, client)
    assert.NotNil(t, server)
    assert.Nil(t, err)

    log.Println("CLIENT1: ", client) // it will output CLIENT1:  &{0xc00073c090 projectID (default)}
    server.AddRPC(

        &pb.BatchGetDocumentsRequest{
            Database:  dbPath,
            Documents: []string{pathUser},
        },
        []interface{}{
            &pb.BatchGetDocumentsResponse{
                Result:   &pb.BatchGetDocumentsResponse_Found{docUser},
                ReadTime: aTimestamp2,
            },
        },
    )
    userDocRef := client.Collection(collections.User).Doc(userID) 
    gotUserDoc, err := userDocRef.Get(ctx)
  
   pbError, err := c.AddUser(ctx, &user.AddUserRequest{
        UserId: userID,
        })
    assert.Nil(t, err)
```

so my issue is that the mock client is always querying path `"projects/projectID/databases/(default)"` not sure how to point this mock client to the right destination of my project id

and the 2nd issue is that actually this method `c.AddUser` is querying the firestore .. so how i can mock all of this and connect the puzzles

libs which i am trying to use
github.com/rjansen/raizel/firestore/mock
github.com/weathersource/go-mockfs

Please point me to some examples...